# When tar the same two packages，its md5 are not same

Tags: linux, compression, tar, md5sum

There are two packages with a file in it.

```shell
[root@build-production test]# ll
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 19 9月  18 07:58 pack1
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 19 9月  18 07:58 pack2
[root@build-production test]# ll pack1
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 2 9月  18 07:58 file1
[root@build-production test]# ll pack2
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 2 9月  18 07:58 file2
```

and the file have the same md5.

```shell
[root@build-production test]# md5sum  pack1/file1 pack2/file2
b026324c6904b2a9cb4b88d6d61c81d1  pack1/file1
b026324c6904b2a9cb4b88d6d61c81d1  pack2/file2
```

but when i tar each packeages with the command below, their tarballs' md5 differ.

```shell
root@build-production test]# GZIP=-n tar zchf  pack1.tar.gz pack1 --mtime='2023-01-01 00:00:00'
[root@build-production test]# GZIP=-n tar zchf  pack2.tar.gz pack2 --mtime='2023-01-01 00:00:00'
[root@build-production test]#
[root@build-production test]# md5sum pack1.tar.gz pack2.tar.gz
629e155e9853f17cbd3dbdb5daf05240  pack1.tar.gz
bca577bda8bc22d600dd91fffc51574c  pack2.tar.gz
```

Is this the expected result? and is there a way to make the md5 value of the compressed file consistent?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The original filename (and path) is stored inside the tar file.
These are not the same (pack1/file1 vs. pack2/file2) resulting in 2 different hashes for the tar files. This is exactly as expected.

In order to have the same md5 hash for both tar files their contents must be truly identical. Not just the stored file(s) content but also the directory structure and time-stamp/permissions on the files/directories must match if you put the entire structure in the tar file.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I understand this part. There is another scenario that I am confused about. I obtained two compressed packages locally from two servers. These two compressed packages were made on the two servers using the same command on the same content (including the same directory structure). Compressed, and set permissions through `--numeric-owner --owner=0 --group=0`, and unified timestamps through `--mtime`. However, the md5 values of the two compressed packages are still inconsistent. What may be the reason for this?